# Switching Modules in Composite Application Block

Tags: cab

I am new to CAB framework. After going through the sample GPS application I understood how a single module is loaded and its view is displayed.

I have a project in which I have 3 forms. Should I create a single module with three different Views for this or should I create three different modules for this.

If I create three views, how do i Switch between these views. And if I am creating three different Modules, how do i switch between these modules.

thanks.

Comment: Please, can someone please help me here?

Answer (score 0):

If you will always use these three forms together, put them in the same module. If you will need only one or two of these forms at a given time, put them in separate modules, so you can load only the forms you need on demand.

I don't understand what you exactly mean by "switch between modules". If you refer to how you select which modules to load at the application start, you do it by overriding the GetModuleCatalog method in the bootstrapper and creating a module catalog inside the overrided method. If you mean how to load modules dinamically at any point in the application, you can do that by using the LoadModule method in the container's IModuleManager object.